# Built a website in windows Operating system and distorted in linux. How do i fix it

Tags: html, css, linux, windows, twitter-bootstrap-3

I cloned a website while practicing using HTML and bootstrap ,I added images also, and overlays for all the images in my windows environment.

Later I had to switch my programming environment to Linux mint , and when I opened it up , some of the images don't display , and the overlay is distorted. 
If i switch back to my windows environment, the website looks good. Just as I had built it initially .

Comment: Could you please provide a screenshot or some code that we could use to understand your problem?

Answer (score 1):

In windows while giving path for images and other files you might have used '\' but linux can only identify '/' while windows can recognize both '\' and '/'. So try using '/' (forward slash) in all your path names.

eg: `<img src="images\abc.png">` can't be understood by linux

So, use

`<img src="images/abc.png">`

Comment: Yes, and the case of filenames is important too; if the filename is "abc.png" then `src="Abc.png"` works in Windows but not in  Linux.

Comment: Worked perfectly , Thanks a lot Vasanthi and Mr Lister !!.    I had written some PNG files as ".PNg" ...   changed them back to .PNG.